# if ! <command> (...) vs. <command> ; if [ $? -eq 0 ] (...)

Tags: scripting, control-flow, shellcheck

I am working on a shell script and decided to check my work via [shellcheck.net](https://www.shellcheck.net/). I am able to get functionally the same behavior of the following two lines in my script:

```
findmnt /dev/sda1 >/dev/null ; if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then echo 1; else echo 0; fi
```

vs.

```
if ! findmnt /dev/sda1 >/dev/null; then echo 0; else echo 1; fi
```

However shellcheck [throws](https://github.com/koalaman/shellcheck/wiki/SC2181):

> SC2181: Check exit code directly with e.g. 'if mycmd;', not indirectly
> with $?.

It is not immediately clear to me which to use. I do see: https://github.com/koalaman/shellcheck/issues/1167 which seems to have amended this for several possible values. I want to be sure that I am writing something that uses best practices and will run without issue and report accurately.

Comment: https://github.com/koalaman/shellcheck/wiki/SC2181 has a rationale for the warning. What kind of answer are you expecting here, other than repeating that rationale?

Comment: `if findmnt /dev/sda1 >/dev/null; then echo 1; else echo 0; fi` would be a more direct equal of the first one. Using `!` there flips the sense of the test.

Comment: Echoing what looks like a exit code is an indication that something *else* should also be looking at the exit code of `findmnt`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You only need to use the special variable `$?` when you need its value across several invocations of other utilities.  For example, you may want to output it in a diagnostic message and then return it from a function. Outputting something with `printf` would reset `$?` to the exit-status of `printf`, so you wouldn't be able to do `return "$?"` (or `return`) directly afterward to return the original exit-status. Notice that even testing something with `[ ... ]` resets `$?`. You would probably instead assign `$?` to some other variable and use that.

You might want to consider using `$?` in an `if` statement if that is the style used in the rest of the project. In that case, remember to quote the expansion, as technically, `$IFS` might contain digits, which means the unquoted expansion of `$?` would potentially disappear entirely or partially.

```bsh
utility

# shellcheck disable=SC2181
if [ "$?" -eq 0 ]; then
    echo ok
else
    echo fail
fi
```

However, this makes for much typing and makes the code slightly obfuscated and a bit unnecessarily tricky to follow.  Note that the invocation of `utility` above is not connected to the `if` statement following it in any immediate way.

There is additionally a bit of extra redundancy here since the `if` statement is now examining the exit-status of the `[` utility to test whether a variable is zero or not. The variable is the exit-status of another utility, which we could have used with `if` directly.

```bsh
if utility; then
    echo ok
else
    echo fail
fi
```

Here it's clear that the invocation of `utility` is an integral part of the `if` statement.

See also [the rationale behind the `SC2181` warning](https://github.com/koalaman/shellcheck/wiki/SC2181) in the ShellCheck wiki.

Comment: Thanks, I think I was trying to get another opinion or idea of what is considered best practices/best form. shellcheck is a great tool, but it's sometimes important for me to read or see other opinions on the matter outside of the tool's maintainers.

Comment: Note that something like `foo; ret=$?; if [ "$ret" = 0 ]; then ....; elif [ "$ret" = 1 ]; then ...; fi` _also requires_ both the explicit test on the exit status (since `if cmd...` can only test for zero vs. non-zero) _and_ requires the temporary variable, since the `[ ... ]` tests also affect `$?` themselves.

Comment: You would also use `$?` directly if you care about the actual value, not just the zero/non-zero distinction that the `if` statement makes. `case $? in ...` is good for this.